# Finding last letters of a string

Tags: c, string

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>

char str[100];

int main(void)
{
    int i, t, j, len;

    printf("Enter string: ");
    scanf("%[^\n]ed", str);

    len = strlen(str);

    str[len] = ' ';

   for (t = 0, i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++)
    {
        if ((str[i] == ' ') && (str[i - 1] == 'd') && (str[i-2]=='e'))
        {
            for (j = t; j < i; j++)
                printf("%c", str[j]);
            t = i + 1;
            printf("\n");
        }
        else
        {
            if (str[i] == ' ')
            {
                t = i + 1; 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This program should find words that end with "ed", after user insert them. If the user didn't insert a word that end with ed, it should print a message like "there no words with ed". I tried to add this:

```
if ((str[i] == ' ') && (str[i - 1] == 'd') && (str[i-2]=='e')=NULL)
printf("There no words with ed");
```

But it didn't work.

Comment: Start with modifying `str[len] = ' ';` to `str[len-1] = ' ';` . Array indexes start with zero in C. `str[len] = ' ' replaces the zero terminator with a space, thus leading to undefined behaviour.

Comment: Accessing `str[i - 1]` when `i` is 0 also leads to undefined behaviour.

Comment: @WhozCraig `str` is global variable. (str are initialized with 0)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

All what you need to make a flag which increments if you found your match; if you want the number of matches; or just to be set; if you want to know state only.

The following is your code included this flag called "found", check that.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>

char str[100];

int main(void)
{
    int i, t, j, len;
    int found = 0;
    printf("Enter string: ");
    scanf("%[^\n]ed", str);

    len = strlen(str);

    str[len] = ' ';

   for (t = 0, i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++)
    {
        if ((str[i] == ' ') && (str[i - 1] == 'd') && (str[i-2]=='e'))
        {
            for (j = t; j < i; j++)
                printf("%c", str[j]);
            t = i + 1;
            printf("\n");
            found++;
        }
        else
        {
            if (str[i] == ' ')
            {
                t = i + 1;
            }
        }
    }
    if(found == 0)
        printf("NotFound\r\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Also, I've a comment on your code:

- The statement `str[len] = ' '` will replace string NULL terminator with ' ' which is not acceptable, you should make sure always that you last element of your string array is NULL(0)

Answer (score 3):

You need to think through the logic of the algorithm before writing any code. If you want to find words that end with "ed", then you obviously need to search at the end of the string, and not at the beginning. Also there are only 2 letters and they are always located at the end, in a specified order, so why would you need a loop to begin with?

Also, how would it make sense to initialize `i` with 0, then use a loop body which contains code like `i-1`?

To get the last letter of a string, you would do like this:

```
size_t last_index = strlen(str) - 1; // -1 because C arrays are 0-indexed.
char last_char = str[last_index];
```

And to get the character before that, use `last_index-1`. Then simply compare those two characters against 'e' and 'd'. There is no need for a loop.

Comment: Note these two lines of code will trip UB if the string is, in fact, length-zero. A 64bit platform with a zero length string will store `18446744073709551615` for the value of `last_index`.

Comment: @WhozCraig Yes and they would also cause UB if `str` was not a string etc etc. So check the user input. That's a separate task not related to the algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

First things first, your `scanf("%[^\n]ed", str);` may not work as you expected when the input is something like "I loved you", in which case the whole line is read in, ignoring the "ed" in the format string.

In fact, there is another approach to achieve your requirement, which is quite simple.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char str[100], *substr;
    size_t len;
    puts("Enter string: ");
    fgets(str, 100, stdin);
    substr = strtok(str, " ");
    while(substr)
    {
        len = strlen(substr);
        if (substr[len - 2] == 'e' && substr[len - 1] == 'd')
            puts(substr);
        substr = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }
}
```

I don't think your own code can be better than the one using `strtok()`. Please keep in mind that taking advantage of standard library functions will make your life much easier.